# Converting List[Option[A]] to Option[List[A]] using Map instead of FlatMap

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, higher-order-functions

In the book [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) there is a question that asks to convert a List of Options into an Option of Lists. The function signature is as follows:

```
def sequence[A](a:List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]]
```

On the book's website, this function is implemented as follows:

```
def sequence[A](a:List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]] = a match {
   case Nil => Some(Nil)
   case h::t => h flatMap (r => sequence(t) map (h::_))
}
```

I am a little confused by the `h flatMap (r => sequence(t) map (h::_))` part. If I break it down, it goes as follows:

h is of type `Option[A]`. Performing flatMap on h would return an `Option[B]` but it takes as a parameter a function f that takes A as a parameter and return an `Option[B]`, now in the example above, `sequence(t) map (h :: _)` would return an `Option[List[A]]` which aligns with the return type of the function.

Can map be used instead of flatMap to perform the transformation from `List[Option[A]]` to `Option[List[A]]`? Also, the solution provided doesn't seem to be tail-recursive. Can it be made tail-recursive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo:

```
case h::t => h flatMap (r => sequence(t) map (h::_))
```

There should be `r :: _`, or `h.toList ::: _`, not `h :: _`

`sequence(t)` returns `Option[List[A]]`. `map (r::_)` on `Option[List[A]]` don't change the type. It just takes a `List[A]` from `Option` if any and prepends it with `A`.

So the type of `sequence(t) map (r :: _)` is `Option[List[A]]`.

You don't need `flatMap` here:

```
def sequence[A](a:List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]] = a match {
   case Nil => Some(Nil)
   case None :: _ => None
   case Some(r) :: t => sequence(t) map (r :: _)
}
```

The solution can be made tail-recursive. The common problem with tail-recursion and `List` is that you have to reverse you list in the end:

```
def sequence[A](a:List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec def loop(a: List[Option[A]], subres: List[A] = Nil): Option[List[A]] =
    a match {
      case Nil => Some(subres)
      case None :: _ => None
      case Some(r) :: t => loop(t, r :: subres)
    }
  loop(a) map {_.reverse}
}
```

In fact it can be made not recursive at all:

```
def sequence[A](a:List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]] =
  a.foldLeft(Option(List[A]())){ (os, oe) =>
    for {
      s <- os
      e <- oe
    } yield e :: s
  }.map{ _.reverse }
```

Comment: The second solution does not work with `sequence(List(Some(1), Some(2),None))`. It returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

`h flatMap (r => sequence(t) map (h::_))` should be `h flatMap (r => sequence(t) map (r::_))` as `h` is of type `Option[A]` and `r` is of type `A`. We are trying to append element to the list of type `List[A]` in the map and hence `r::_`.

Another solution without using recursion would be:

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]])(implicit nullValue: A):Option[List[A]] = {
 Option(a map { x => x.getOrElse(nullValue)})
}
```

Comment: the `nullValue` depends on what the user wishes to be put in list when the element is `None`. Will have to be mentioned. For ex: `sequence(List(Some(1), Some(2),None))(-1)`. If user wishes to omit `None`, then a different issue

Comment: method `sequence` in the question returns `None` if not all elements of the source collection are `Some`.

Comment: It works like `if (a.forall(_.isDefined)) Some(a.map{ _.get }) else None`

Comment: @senia Oh ok. Thanks. My fault then. I had added a default value in cases it is None.

Comment: `a map {_.getOrElse(default)}` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to implement the seq function that is not using recursion implicitely:

```
def seq[A](a: List[Option[A]]):Option[List[A]] = a.foldLeft(Some(Nil):Option[List[A]])((collected,elem) => elem.flatMap(el=> collected.map(el::_)))
```